# plotting from two different data files in a single graph gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have two different data files named `try_giants.dat` and `parameters_ks.dat`. I want to plot 3rd column of 1st file vs. 2nd column of 2nd file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With datafiles `D1.csv`

```
0 1 0
0 1 1
0 1 2
0 1 3
0 1 4
```

and `D2.csv`

```
0 10
0 20
0 30
0 40
0 50
```

you can plot the third column of `D1.csv` on the x-axis and the second column of `D2.csv` on the y-axis with

```
plot "< paste D1.csv D2.csv" u 3:5 w l
```

The [paste](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/upaste.htm) command merges corresponding or subsequent lines of files giving you this output:

```
0 1 0   0 10
0 1 1   0 20
0 1 2   0 30
0 1 3   0 40
0 1 4   0 50
```

Hence, the third column of this file is the third column of `D1.csv` and the fifth column is the second column of `D2.csv` resulting in this plot:

[image]